# Following error in cakephp 2.7.3

Tags: cakephp-2.7

Notes for CakePHP 2.7.3.

Notice (1024): Please change the value of 'Security.salt' in APP/Config/core.php to a salt value specific to your application. [CORE\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php, line 846]

Notice (1024): Please change the value of 'Security.cipherSeed' in APP/Config/core.php to a numeric (digits only) seed value specific to your application. [CORE\Cake\Utility\Debugger.php, line 850]

Comment: So what is your question? Please see [hot to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

go to cake/utility/Debugger.php.

Make changings at the last. write some alphabets and write some numeric numbers in upper last and last line.

You wouldn't see this type of error